# Dropdown list with single table value in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My table "tasks" have; projectname column, employee column and task column. I want to create 3 drodown list. First dropdown list is to select projectname, when projectname selected, next dropdown will shows who are the employees and other drop down list will shows what are the tasks. Can anyone help me with this problem?
Controller

```
public function Income(){

    $data['projectname'] = $this->welcome4->show_students(); 
    $data['tasks'] = $this->welcome4->show_students2(); 

    $this->load->view('template/navigation');
    $this->load->view('template/sideNav');
    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('Income',$data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer');

    }
```

Model

```
function show_students(){
        $query = $this->db->get('task');
        $query_result = $query->result();
        return $query_result;
    } 
    function show_students2(){
        $query = $this->db->get('task');
        $query_result = $query->result();
        return $query_result;
    }
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
                             <label>Select Project</label>
                        </div>     


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select name="projectname" class="input form-control">
                        <option value="none" selected="selected">Select Project</option>


                        <?php foreach($projects as $s):?> 
                        <option value="<?php echo $s->projectname?>"><?php echo $s->projectname?></option>
                        <?php endforeach;?>  
                        </select>
                    </div>



                    <div class="form-group">
                             <label>Select task</label>
                        </div> 

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select name="task" class="input form-control">
                        <option value="none" selected="selected">Select Task</option>


                        <?php foreach($task as $s):?> 
                        <option value="<?php echo $s->task?>"><?php echo $s->employee?></option>
                        <?php endforeach;?>  
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a minimal code to simulate your problem so that we can have a closer look?

Comment: What is the problem in this?

Comment: Mr.Sahan I add my code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375374/populating-a-dropdown-based-on-the-selection-of-another-dropdown-using-jquery-in